# Using a mask to replace values in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have this piece of code, and next, I would like to use the mask to replace the elements in 'arr' that are multiple of 3 by the double of its value, but I can't find an easy way to do it.

```
     import numpy as np
     li = list(range(3,150,4))
     arr = np.array(li)
     mask = arr%3==0
     n_mult= np.count_nonzero(mask)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You can simply do `arr[mask]*=2`

Comment: Also, to begin, you could have done `arr = np.arange(3,150,4)`.